# BindingList to DataGridView, but get empty cells

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I'm trying to place BindingList data into a default DataGridView, but without success. If I run the Form, it shows a DataGridView with empty rows. So the number of rows is correct, but the data itself is missing.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    'Declare BindingList
    Dim bList As BindingList(Of User)

    'Init BindingList Constructor
    bList = New BindingList(Of User)()

    'List -> BindingList
    'Dim bindingList = New BindingList(Of Person)(list)

    'BindingList Settings
    bList.AllowNew = True
    bList.AllowRemove = True
    bList.AllowEdit = True
    bList.RaiseListChangedEvents = True

    'Add Object
    bList.Add(New User() With {.id = 1, .firstName = "Jeff", .lastName = "Tree"})
    bList.Add(New User() With {.id = 2, .firstName = "Loes", .lastName = "Stone"})

    'BindingList -> DataGridView
    Dim source = New BindingSource(bList, Nothing)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bList
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class User
    Sub New()
    End Sub

Public id As Integer
Public firstName As String
Public lastName As String

End Class
```

Result:

[image: DataViewGrid without the values]

Comment: Have you manually added the columns via designer at design time?  Or are those columns getting added at runtime automatically when you bind the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User` class only contains public fields (which cannot be used for data binding). You should use properties instead:

```
Public Class User
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
End Class
```

Then, you can either remove the columns that you manually added to the DataGridView (in which case, they will be automatically generated for you) or you can set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the DGV to false, but in that case, you will also need to set the `DataPropertyName` property of each column to match the property name in your class.